# Channels in Go, and emitters in node.js?

Tags: node.js, go, eventemitter

Does Go have an equivalent of node.js' "emitter"?

I'm teaching myself Go by porting over a node.js library I wrote. In the node version, the library emits an event once something happens (e.g. it listens on UDP port 1234 and when "ABC" is received, "abcreceived" is emitted so the calling code can respond as necessary (e.g. sending back "DEF")

I've seen channels in Go (and am currently reading up on them), but as I'm still new to this language, I don't know if (or how, for that matter) that can be used to communicate with whatever code is using my library.

I've also seen https://github.com/chuckpreslar/emission, but am not sure if this is acceptable, or if there's a better ("Best practice") way of doing things.

Comment: This is a bit broad. Are you asking how to use channels? If you have a basic understanding of channels, then all you need do is allow your consumers to reference it; perhaps via a `yourpackage.EventChan()` method

Comment: @SimonWhitehead: I'm asking if channels are the way to go, or if there is an equivalent to node.js' EventEmitter. I'm reading up on channels, but you're suggesting I make a new channel in my library called (e.g.) EventChan and use it like an EventEmitter (e.g. if channel has "abcreveived" in it, do something)?

As mentioned, I'm still learning Go, so I'm still wrapping my head around some of the concepts

Comment: @Grayda I highly recommend to read this answer http://bit.ly/1He8sQU

Comment: @wonsky Thanks for the link. I had a good read through the pages (most I'd seen before, but I went and re-read them) and had a go at  adding channels to my code in the form of a switch statement. I added a var "Events" which is exported and therefore grabbable by my consumer code.

Now I can add a value to my channel (e.g. abcreceived), grab the item in my consumer code and act accordingly.

It's not as straightforward as node.js' EventEmitter / .on('event', function() { }); thing, but it does the trick.

Answer (score 2):

Go and Node.js are very different. Node.js supports concurrency only via callbacks. There might be various ways of dressing them up, but they're fundamentally callbacks.

In Node.js, there is *no* parallelism; Node.js has a single-threaded runtime. When Node.js `async` is used to achieve what is called 'parallel' execution, it isn't parallel in the sense used in Go, but concurrent.

[Concurrency is not parallelism](https://talks.golang.org/2012/waza.slide#1) in the Go world.

Go has explicit concurrency based on Communicating Sequential Processes (CSP), a mathematical basis conceived by Tony Hoare at Oxford. The runtime interleaves cooperating processes called goroutines by time-slicing them onto the available CPU cores. Within each goroutine, the code is *single threaded*, so is easy to write. In the simple case, no data is shared between goroutines; instead messages pass between them along channels. In this way, there is no need for callbacks.

When goroutines get blocked waiting for I/O, that's OK because they don't use any CPU time until they're unblocked. Their memory footprint is slight and you can have very large numbers of them. So callbacks are not needed for I/O operations either.

Because the execution models of Go and Node.js are about as different as they could be, attempting to port code from one to the other is very likely to lead to very clumsy solutions. It's better to start from the original requirements and implement from scratch.

It would be possible to distort the Go concurrency model using function arguments to behave like callbacks. This would be a bad idea because it would not be idiomatic and would lose the benefits that CSP gives.

Comment: Thanks for the lesson! I suppose I need to brush up on my deeper knowledge of such things. Because my library is mostly network based, porting hasn't been as bad. Most of the difficulty has been with me learning as I code (which is also how I mastered node, not 6 months ago!) and the rest is simple funcs with just-as-simple switches and if statements.

Comment: Node has no parallelism, really?! Then how does Promise.all() work? I think it's only half-baked knowledge to say that the environment is single-threaded. It's only the event loop that's single-threaded; behind the scenes, there's a thread pool to pass off I/O to and achieve high concurrency. I this respect, Go's internals are no different as it uses a thread pool, too.

Comment: Perhaps that's missing the difference between parallelism and concurrency. Node promises provide *concurrency*, just as futures do in Scala and other languages. But they aren't providing *parallelism* if the execution model doesn't use parallel hardware underneath. Goroutines provide both concurrency and parallelism; multiple CPU cores are able to contribute to the processing.

Answer (score 1):

So by reading others' Go code and some links in the comments to my question, I think channels are the way to go.

In my library code (semi pseudo-code):

```
// Make a new channel called "Events"
var Events = make(chan 

func doSomething() {
    // ...
    Events <-"abcreceived" // Add "abcreceived" to the Events channel
}
```

And in the code that will use my library:

```
evt := <-mylib.Events

switch evt {
    case "abcreceived":
        sendBackDEF()
        break
    // ...
}
```

I still prefer node.js' EventEmitter (because you can transfer data back easily) but for simple things, this should suffice.

Comment: a value passed down a channel can only be consumed once, so it's a not a great replacement. A well written Go solution is not going to look like a well written Node solution. Node might use a callback or an event to prevent blocking while in Go you can use a go routine to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: @jmaloney For notification of events, that's all you really need, as any recurring events (e.g. receiving ABC more than once) will push a new item on the channel for consumption. For things where you need something to stay around (e.g. a "are we currently receiving ABC?"), channels don't seem to be the way to go (you'd expose a bool containing that info, I suppose)